# Weird indention on my model

Tags: modeling

[image]

Strange indentions on my model. I don't know what's causing this, can anyone help?

[image]

Another photo of the glitch

Comment: Recalculate your normals first by going into edit mode, selecting all and pressing Ctrl+N.

Comment: Ah, thanks! That cleared up the issue a bit, but there is still a strange seam thing on the bottom shoulder guard.

Comment: Upload a new screenshot in edit mode. Try removing doubles, W > R. Try clearing creases https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/edges.html?highlight=crease#edge-crease.

Comment: If you're talking about the weird cross on the circle, that's probably because of smooth shading and also having too little faces, try selecting it and pressing CTRL + 1 in object mode to add subdivsion.

Comment: Ok guys, there were like 100 doubles in there. Thanks for the fix!

Comment: @Leander You can provide an answer explaining how you fixed his issue using recalculating normals then removing the doubles :)